# second or nested event.PreventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code snippet, if I uncomment the first preventDefault() it will work fine, but I'm trying to invoke the second preventDefault(), but it won't work. See below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function (event) {
        if ($('#tracking').val() != "") {
            // FIRST preventDefault()
            //event.preventDefault();
            var url = "/ReceivingLog/CheckTrackingNumber?number=" + $('#tracking').val();
            $.get(url, null, function (result) {
                if (result == "False") {
                    // SECOND preventDefault()
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Why is the second/nested preventDefault not working? How do I get the second preventDefault() to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get` is asynchronous - by the time its response comes back, the outer thread has already finished, and the triggered event has completed normally. You'll have to trigger the event again after the response comes back:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', clickListener);

let doSubmit = false;
function clickListener(e) {
  // If this was triggered by the `$.get`, return immediately, run the event as normal without interruption:
  if (doSubmit) {
    console.log('redirecting');
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  //$.get(url, ...
  setTimeout(() => {
    const success = true;
    if (success) {
      doSubmit = true;
      button.click();
    }
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<form>
<button type="submit">click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: okay now I totally get the explanation you gave, but I still have a problem applying your example in my case. Do I need to create clickListener function?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a standalone function to pass as a listener that you can call later, just like `clickListener` in my snippet. (or you could submit the form instead of clicking the button again)